# (lldb) Print unsigned long long in hex

Tags: objective-c, debugging, hex, lldb, unsigned-long-long-int

I am trying to debug my Objective-C program, and I need to print my `unsigned long long` variable in hex. I am using the `lldb` debugger.

In order to print `short` as hex, [you can use this](http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html):

```
(lldb) type format add --format hex short
(lldb) print bit
(short) $11 = 0x0000
```

However, I can't make it work for `unsigned long long`.

```
// failed attempts:
(lldb) type format add --format hex (unsigned long long)
(lldb) type format add --format hex unsigned long long
(lldb) type format add --format hex unsigned decimal
(lldb) type format add --format hex long long
(lldb) type format add --format hex long
(lldb) type format add --format hex int
```

I am running an iOS app on simulator, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

type format add expects the type name as a single word -- you need to quote the argument if it is multiple words.  e.g.

```
   2    {
   3      unsigned long long a = 10;
-> 4      a += 5;
   5      return a;
   6    }
(lldb) type form add -f h "unsigned long long"
(lldb) p a
(unsigned long long) $0 = 0x000000000000000a
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 49):

You can use format letters. Link to GDB docs (works for LLDB too): https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Formats.html#Output-Formats

```
(lldb) p a
(unsigned long long) $0 = 10
(lldb) p/x a
(unsigned long long) $1 = 0x000000000000000a
```

Comment: Note that whereas gdb accepts a space in between `p` and `/x`, lldb does not, so `p /x` works in gdb, but in lldb it has to be `p/x`.

Comment: @Vlad can you point to more specific link to the all the commands?

Comment: @DeveloperSheldon Seems like the link has been expired. I've edited my answer, so now it contains working link to all output formats of GDB. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the rest of the [document](http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html), I found out it is possible to do something like this:

```
// ObjC code
typedef int A;
```

then,

```
(lldb) type format add --format hex A
```

This gave me the idea to `typedef unsigned long long BigInt` :

```
// ObjC code
typedef unsigned long long BigInt;
```

then,

```
(lldb) type format add --format hex BigInt
```

Works like a charm.